# Display an image without writing it's path

Tags: javascript, php, html

I couldn't find a better title, feel free to edit.

I want to use a script as an image src attribute like so :

```
<img src="img.js"/>
```

*Note* : I don't care if it is a javascript or php or whatever language.

Here is my folder content :

- index.html
- img.js
- 3.jpg

I want to display that "3.jpg" image via "img.js"

I tried this :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "3.jpg";
document.append(img);
```

but it doesn't work.

I can see that the js script is not called because when I add a console.log call it won't show anything in the console.

How can I do this ? Is it possible ?

The aim is :

- have a server-side script that choose what image to display.
- don't write the path to the image in the HTML

Comment: *"The aim is to have a server-side script that choose what image to display."* Then you have to write a server-side script which returns image data. JS code is not image data.

Comment: `<img src="img.js">` using JavaScript like this is running javascript on the client side, not on the server.

Comment: @maček: Just noticed, however `<img src="img.js">` won't execute the JS because the browser doesn't expect to get JS. It just sees a corrupt image.

Comment: @FelixKling that's true. I guess all I'm trying to say is there's no server-side language being used in the question.

Comment: Well you are right, the javascript was the first step to test if it's feasible. I can switch to another language, the problem is the same, how to show the image ?

Comment: @FelixKling yes, console.log call does not log anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<img src=...`  expects image data from the specified URL. You can't dump Javascript into as source, because that's not an image - it's code. The browser is going to treat the JS code as if it was image data, try to figure out what KIND of image it is (jpg, gif, png, etc...) and go "wtf is this?" and just display a broken image icon.

Whatever URL you do point the image's source has to output that raw binary image data, e.g.

html:

```
<img src="img.php" />
```

img.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('3.jpg');
```

Comment: This seems to be a great answer ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="<?php include "img.php" ?>"/>`

In img.php:

```
<?
echo "3.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what happens here? I'm sure the OP appreciates an explanation.

Comment: I understand, thank you. He is writing the correct image source into the html code using PHP. But I don't want to write the image path into the HTML, that's the tricky part =)

Comment: So you should as Mark B did. haha

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dummy").attr("src", '3.png').css("display", "block");
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<img id="dummy" style="display:none" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

this is an example, but as previous posts suggest, it sounds like having a server side script like php is what you are after?

Comment: The aim is to avoid writing the image path ("[...]3.jpg") in the HTML.

Comment: I see you have found a php answer, but if you dont't want to use php or if you know how many images you have and they are named 0.png, 1.png etc, you can either pick randomly or show them by range

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++ ){
        $("body").append('<img src="'+i+'.png" />');
    }